# Android Proguard - IllegalArgumentException in Jackson's TypeReference class

Tags: android, jackson, proguard, illegalargumentexception

Android application crashes if proguard is used for obfuscating. Below is the stacktrace.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Internal error: 
  TypeReference constructed without actual type information
    at a.b.a.g.b.<init>(TypeReference.java:35)
    at a.c.d.q.<init>(StdCouchDbInstance.java:22)
    at a.c.d.p.<clinit>(StdCouchDbInstance.java:22)
```

I am using the `EktorpClient` library(To work with the couchdb) and `StdCouchDbInstance.java` refers to [this](https://github.com/helun/Ektorp/blob/master/org.ektorp/src/main/java/org/ektorp/impl/StdCouchDbInstance.java) file and `TypeReference.java` is in [this](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.9.2/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/type/package-frame.html) package. Any suggestion as to what option I should use in the Proguard config file to overcome this problem?

Comment: no. not yet. need to see how I can skip jackson.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I just ran into this problem using Proguard with an Ektorp dependency. The TypeReference is a generic, and `-keepattributes Signature` will keep generic information.

I actually used the following, which solved my issue.

```
-keepattributes Signature,*Annotation*,EnclosingMethod
```

From the [Proguard Examples](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/#manual/examples.html):

> The "Signature" attribute is required to be able to access generic types when compiling in JDK 5.0 and higher.

Comment: I have `-keepattributes Signature` in my ProGuard rules, but yet I'm still getting that error. I'm in kotlin, constructing an anonymous object based on the TypeReference class, if that matters.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like ProGuard is mishandling generic type information (passing of Type parameters) somehow. I don't know if this would be a known ProGuard issue; but you might check Jackson users mailing list if others have encountered this. Also, you could try different Jackson version, although I don't think class `TypeReference` has changed a lot.